# How to make a QED symbol based on Unicode's Lower Right Triangle?

Tags: symbols

I want to make a symbol which looks like the unicode lower right triangle `U+25FF` but with the same size and line thickness as the `\qed` symbol.

If I resized the unicode symbol with `\resizebox` the line thickness wouldn't be the same, so  I need a new symbol. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `amsthm.sty` we find

```
% amsthm.sty, line 422:
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
% amsthm.sty, line 430:
\providecommand{\qedsymbol}{\openbox}
```

so we want to build a triangle based on those dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,pict2e}

\usepackage{color} % for the comparison

\newcommand{\opentriangle}{%
  \raisebox{0.2pt}{\makebox[0.77778em]{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.6em}%
    \linethickness{0.4pt}%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \polygon(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\opentriangle}

\begin{document}

First a comparison: 
\openbox\opentriangle\quad
\makebox[0pt][l]{\openbox}\textcolor{red}{\opentriangle}\quad
\makebox[0pt][l]{\opentriangle}\textcolor{red}{\openbox}

\begin{proof}
The two symbols are not exactly one half of the other, 
but the difference can't be noticed if they aren't
superimposed on each other.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the main document font, you might prefer round joins:

[image]

Just change the code into

```
\newcommand{\opentriangle}{%
  \raisebox{0.2pt}{\makebox[0.77778em]{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.6em}%
    \linethickness{0.4pt}\roundjoin
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \polygon(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're free to use the `stix` math font package, you could make use of its `\lrtriangle` -- shorthand for "lower right triangle, I suppose -- macro. The package's `\square` and `\lrtriangle` macros produce symbols that have the same size and line thickness.

To make `\lrtriangle` the QED symbol, one could load the [amsthm](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) or [ntheorem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package and execute `\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\lrtriangle}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix,color}
\begin{document}
$\square \lrtriangle$

% same horizontal and vertical dim., same line thickness:
$\square\color{red}\kern-9.1pt\lrtriangle$
\end{document}
```